# VirtualBox and Virtual machines - CPU virtualization

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am always concerned about disk space and performance and have recently installed Virtual Box to run a Virtual Machine for testing.

Other than occupying disk space is there any disadvantage to running a virtual machine and leaving virtualization enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: For basic uses, you will not feel much difference between a virtual and a physical machine when it comes to performance (other than the need to manage it or sometimes driver issues). But for advanced needs, a vm is much less efficient than a physical machine, as it is "just another program" that is running on your main os and is subjected to it's priorities and hardware compabilities. This difference is so great, that another type of virtualisation method exists that is an entire dedicated os for virtualisations.

Comment: You can read more about this subject here: [Vmware - What is a Hypervisor?](https://www.vmware.com/topics/glossary/content/hypervisor), [What is Hypervisor and what types of hypervisors are there](https://vapour-apps.com/what-is-hypervisor/)